mdadm - reshape operation stuck after system rebooted while the operation was ongoing
I am trying to bring a volume online on an Asustor AS6212RD. The NAS has been irresponsive for about a month (details below), and data on the volume cannot be accessed. I can see the folder structure on the web console, but the folders are empty.
Disclaimer: I do not own the system and do not have a complete history. I was asked to take a look because of my experience with Hardware RAID and Windows Storage Servers.
Short Description: The system went down while a volume was being reshaped as a result of upgrading RAID5 to RAID6. The reshaping process has been stuck at 1.5% for a month.
Current Status:
root@PLGDIM:~ # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md1 : active raid6 sdd4[5] sdb4[8](S) sde4[6] sda4[4]
      7804860416 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/3] [UUU__]
      [>....................]  reshape =  1.5% (62074180/3902430208) finish=117391118.1min speed=0K/sec

md126 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[7]
      2094080 blocks super 1.2 [4/2] [UU__]

md0 : active raid1 sda2[13]
      2095104 blocks super 1.2 [12/1] [___U________]

unused devices: <none>

root@PLGDIM:~ # mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Mar  4 17:47:47 2020
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 7804860416 (7443.29 GiB 7992.18 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3902430208 (3721.65 GiB 3996.09 GB)
      Raid Devices : 5
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Tue Jun 25 07:07:02 2024
             State : clean, degraded, reshaping
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : resync

    Reshape Status : 1% complete
     Delta Devices : 1, (4->5)

              Name : AS6212R-D56F:1
              UUID : a8417c38:c72fdc8d:7a50a576:ec09dca5
            Events : 387965

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       5       8       52        0      active sync   /dev/sdd4
       4       8        4        1      active sync   /dev/sda4
       6       8       68        2      active sync   /dev/sde4
       -       0        0        3      removed
       -       0        0        4      removed

       8       8       20        -      spare   /dev/sdb4

I can't tell what the 2 lines that says "removed" mean.
This is what I see on the web console
The logs revealed the following information
-----
INFO    6/7/2024 16:20  SYSTEM  [Disk Doctor] S.M.A.R.T quick scanning of Disk 1 result: completed without error.
INFO    6/7/2024 16:20  SYSTEM  [Disk Doctor] S.M.A.R.T quick scanning of Disk 1 has finished.
INFO    6/7/2024 16:17  SYSTEM  [Disk Doctor] S.M.A.R.T quick scanning of Disk 1 has started.
-----
WARNING 6/4/2024 20:09  SYSTEM  [Disk] Disk in slot 7 was removed.
-----
INFO    6/4/2024 20:07  SYSTEM  [System] System is restarting.
INFO    6/4/2024 19:56  SYSTEM  [Disk] Disk plugged in to slot 7.
INFO    6/4/2024 19:55  SYSTEM  [Disk] Disk plugged in to slot 4.
INFO    6/4/2024 19:55  SYSTEM  [Disk] Disk plugged in to slot 3.
INFO    6/4/2024 19:55  SYSTEM  [Disk] Disk plugged in to slot 1.
WARNING 6/4/2024 19:54  SYSTEM  [System] The NAS did not shut down properly last time.
INFO    6/4/2024 19:54  SYSTEM  [System] System starts.
-----
INFO    5/31/2024 16:57 SYSTEM  [Volume] Volume 1 reshaping to 5-disk RAID 6 volume.
INFO    5/31/2024 16:57 admin   [Volume] Added 1 disk(s) to Volume 1.
-----
INFO    5/29/2024 17:23 admin   [Volume] Removed spare disk (slot 7) from Volume 1.
INFO    5/29/2024 17:22 admin   [Volume] Disk on slot 7 has become the spare disk for Volume 1.
-----
INFO    5/29/2024 15:56 SYSTEM  [Disk] Disk plugged in to slot 7.
-----

As you can see, a disk was added to slot 7 and volume 1 was reshaped from RAID5 to RAID6. The system went down after a few days. The volume used disks on slot 1,2,3,4 and the additional disk was added to slot 7. What I find strange is that the logs dont indicate that a disk was plugged into slot 2 after it came back online. Disk on slot 7 was pulled out shortly after (probably in desperation).
I am guessing the problem started either: when the system did not detect the disk in slot 2
or: when disk on slot 7 was pulled out.
Things I have tried
root@PLGDIM:~ # mdadm --misc --stop /dev/md1

root@PLGDIM:~ # mdadm --misc --readonly /dev/md1

root@PLGDIM:~ # mdadm --misc --action=idle /dev/md1

root@PLGDIM:~ # mdadm --misc --action=frozen /dev/md1

All attempts at the commands just freezes the terminal.
I also tried overriding /sys/block/md1/md/sync_action but it says operation not permitted.
I am not sure what to try next and seeking help from the community. Is there a way to stop the reshape operation and restart it?
As a last resort, I am prepared to reboot the system but I am not sure what the consequences will be.

It looks now like fully degraded but still accessible RAID6 array. Is data still available? If yes, just copy it somewhere, then recreate, that's by far easiest. If not, stop the array now and begin dumping images of all hard drives [or, at least, component devices] to some spare storage (yeah, you'd need a lot of space, nothing can be done about it). Then, mdadm --examine for all component devices...

Thanks Nikita. The data is not accessible. I’m attempting to take images of the drive but unfortunately I cannot identify which drives were in the raid array since a lot of people have touched this system since it broke. I’ll write an update once I figure out which drives were part of the array. Might even need to dump images for all the drives.

Then simply examine all partitions of these drives. It should be possible to guess which were where. If you haven't had enough experience with Linux software RAID, however, I'm afraid you better find a paid data recovery service... and all the people who messed with it and attempt to know what exactly and in what sequence they did. There might be still a ray of a hope...

dmesg, mdadm --examine for /dev/sd?4? If you're lucky it's just a kernel bug and might resume after reboot / in a newer kernel. But if it died mid-reshape, that's very annoying to recover you can't just mdadm --create since half your data is in the new layout, other half is old layout... It involves too many variables to write up a good answer... also too complicated for people to follow through. Discussed, previously, without much success...
